# Date format in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel formula as follows:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE("Sep-15"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

It simply converts the string `"Sep-15"` to the date format that I want. The thing is this same formula is giving different results when I opened the workbook in 2 different systems. In one machine, it gave me `"01/09/2015"`, which is exactly what I wanted. In another it was `"15-09-2016"`. I guess the reason for that is because the second machine thinks 15 refers to the date, not the year. I tried changing the timezone and date format of the second computer to match that of machine 1 **(Australian "dd/mm/yyyy")** but the result is still the same.

Can anyone give me some guidance on what I should have done here? Thanks.

Comment: `=TEXT(DATEVALUE("Sep-01-2015"), "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the "01" day part if that's what you want:

```
=DATEVALUE("01"&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

May also refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/335132/how-do-i-parse-a-nonstandard-date-format-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

Dates are actually numbers. Can you get away with just using a numeric instead?

As for the actual problem, it's possible that you have a local issue. I would check the locales of both systems.

It's possible that you can also use VBA to populate the date. 
For example, using formulas, a UK locale you could use:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE("Sep-01-2015"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

.. but on a German locale it would need:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE("Sep-01-2015"), "tt/mm/jjjj")
```

However, you may be able to use VBA to populate the cell without formulas - depends on you set up I reckon.

You could also try something like, setting the format of the cell to General and using:
=DAY(42380) & "." &  MONTH(42380) & "." & YEAR(42380)

Hope that helps.